# Request body unresolved variable Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to make a simple registration route using node and express. For some reason the req.body.name is being highlighted as unresolved variable name.
While running in postman it is giving a validation error and saying "Path `{PATH}` is required."

My javascript code:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var participant = new Participant({

    name:req.body.name, // this is the place where unresolved variable is coming
    regno:req.body.regno,
    gender : req.body.gender,
    email : req.body.email,
    mobile : req.body.mobile,
    room : req.body.room,
    adgid : req.body.adgid

});

participant.save(function(err,docs) {
    if(docs) {

        res.json({
            "message":docs
        })
    }
    else{
        res.json({
            code: '1',
            message: err
        })
    }
});
```

My model file:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var participantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     name:{ type: String , required :true},
     regno:{ type:String, required :true },
     gender:{ type:String, required :true },
     mobile:{ type: Number ,required :true },
     email:{ type:String,required :true },
     room:{ type:String ,required :true },
    adgid : {type:String , required : true}
});

   var Participant = mongoose.model('Participant', participantSchema);
   module.exports= {Participant : Participant};
```

Comment: You should check the error from `participant.save(function(err, docs) {...`. And look at the `req.body`. I think the name is missing there

Comment: how are you querying through postman?

Comment: Please post code of your `index.js`/`app.js`.

Comment: `var participant = new Participant({ ` .. you need to finish this line. the router post function is malformed

Comment: add body-parser middleware.